# Rails nested form with unknown columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I'm creating an admin interface where the admin (of a company) can add custom fields to their employees.

Example:

**Models:**

- **Employee**: Basic info like name, contact info, etc (has_many employee_field_values)
- **EmployeeFields**: These are the dynamic ones the admin can add (every company has different needs, it could be anything), lets say `favorite_food`
- **EmployeeFieldValues**: The actual values based on the fields above, say `pizza` (belongs_to both models above)

What's a smart way of adding the `EmployeeFieldValues` fields while editing an employee?

I'm trying something simple like this, but not sure if I like it

```
# Controller
@custom_fields = EmployeeFields.all

# View
<%= form_for(@employee) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>

  <% @custom_fields.each do |custom_field| %>
    <%= custom_field.name %>
    <%= text_field_tag "employee_field_values[#{custom_field.name}]" %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit :save %>
<% end %>
```

And then when updating, `params[:employee_field_values]` gives this:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"favorite_food"=>"pizza"}>
```

So, not sure if this is a good direction, also I'm not sure how to handle future edits to an employee's custom_fields if they change.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better to use EmployeeField as nested model and EmployeeFieldValue for select field.
For example:

**Models**

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :name, presence: true

  has_many :employee_field_values

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employee_field_values, reject_if: ->(x) { x[:value].blank? }

end

class EmployeeFieldValue < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :employee_field

end

class EmployeeField < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :employee_field_values, inverse_of: :employee_field, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness: true

end
```

**Controller**

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @employee = Employee.new
    @employee.employee_field_values.build
  end

end
```

**View**

```
= simple_form_for @employee, url: '/' do |f|
  = f.input :name

  = f.simple_fields_for :employee_field_values do |ff|
    = ff.input :value
    = ff.input :employee_field_id, collection: EmployeeField.all.map{|x| [x.title, x.id]}
```

Also you need to make buttons for adding/removing :employee_field_value, and you can do it with [gem cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) for example

**OR** you can build all objects in controller(for each EmployeeField) and do without select box